# Consul health check script is not showing output on UI

Tags: consul

[image: Script file]

Im not able to see the script output on consul UI...
The script runs but the output is not seen
What is that I'm missing or going wrong please help ! :/ :/[image: Consul Output]

Answer (score 3):

The following information is correct for Consul up to 0.7.2 and is subject to change in the future.

The output of a check is only updated in real time when the state of the check changes (i.e. when it goes from `OK` to `WARNING` or `CRITICAL` to `OK`).  The actual text of the check will be updated periodically based Consul's anti-entropy runs, which default to happening every 10 minutes, iirc.  If you're patient, the output will be updated.  Or if you go to the Consul agent running the check and query the appropriate `/v1/agent` endpoint, it should be real-time.  But if you query through the Consul Server's catalogs, it can be delayed.

This trade off in freshness was made due to scalability reasons and not wanting to continually stream hojilions of check updates into a single set of servers.

Comment: I have no idea why this got a downvote? Just found it a have verified that it is indeed the correct answer!